# JavaFX DatePicker: can it be Year and Month only, without Days?

Tags: java, javafx, jfoenix

I'm working on a project and i want to make my jfoenix date picker to pick only year and month is anyone knows how done this ?

Comment: No, it is a "date picker," not a month/year picker. You would need to either build your own or find a library that offers such a control. You would also need to implement your own data model for the value since Java does not include a `MonthYear` or similar object.

Comment: It’s hard for me to imagine a user interface for this that would be any better than just a combo box for the month and a spinner for the year.

Comment: @James_D Here is another [option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month)